# conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1 when enabling proguard

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I'm trying to set up proguard for our existing app. It has a bunch of .jar files in the libs folder and these packages are specified in the build path.. They threw bunch of errors until i added -dontwarn for all the package related errors...

Now when I try to export, i get the converstion error without any messages in the console.. It doesn't say anything.. I looked at other questions but none of them answer my questions..

I'm using the latest proguard and r15 for the SDK..

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the newest ProGuard jars from the project's website, and replace the ones in the SDK folder.

Comment: Try latest ADT? 16.0.1 currently. Works for me with latest ProGuard libs.